# Does receiving one push notification or multiple push notification have any different effect on battery usage?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to find out, what exactly happens in the Push Notification mechanism. What I understood from the literature I have researched is that the APNS requires the iPhone to be constantly connected to the Apple servers and when a notification arrives at the server, it is just forwarded to the device. So from this, is it right to draw a conclusion that whether a device recieve one notification in say an hour, or ten notifications in the same time, it consumes the same battery regardless. Please correct me if I am wrong, since I am going mad thinking about this. There was no direct answer regarding this and I am surprised nobody had this doubt.
Anyways I thank in anticipation for a proper answer and a good reasoning behind the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that sending ten notifications an hour will consume more battery than one notification an hour. The reason is that when each notification arrives, it will wake your screen to show you that there's a new notification, and that consumes battery.